# implement COM interface type library in python

Tags: python, com

I have a plugin that I'm trying to create as a sample for an application from the company I work for.  I'm trying to write this plugin in Python.

The way the plugin architecture works is that the plugin needs to implement an interface defined in a provided COM type library.  So it is a COM client to that type library and in the end gets registered as a COM Server to the registry and the application by giving it the ClassID for late-bound COM by the application.

I'm using pythoncom and win32com and have used makepy.py to generate the needed python code from the type libarary but I can't seem to find a way to create a class that implements the interface from this type library.

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

When I try to run Dispatch to get the COM object I get the following exeption:

`>>> interface = win32com.client.Dispatch('{68AC7909-804F-4D6D-861C-8382DAA7B029}')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `win32com.client.Dispatch()`:

`object = win32com.client.Dispatch("Class.Name")`

This is the example from ActiveState quick start guide:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> w=win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
>>> w.Visible=1
>>> w
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 8.0 Object Library._Application>
```

If it doesn't work, you can use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureModule()` to make sure you've
generated the right cache module.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from win32com.client import gencache

# This comes from running: makepy.py -i "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library"
gencache.EnsureModule('{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 1, 7)
obj = Dispatch("Excel.Application.14")

# gives <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library._Application instance ...>
print repr(obj)
```

The same thing with comtypes (simpler and supports custom interfaces)

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
obj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Comment: Yeah I did try that and I get: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

Comment: @Caleb: And you got <COMObject *> instead of <win32com.gen_py.*>? In that case you should use `win32com.gencache.EnsureModule()`. makepy tells you that exact line you should write. See my edit for an example.

Comment: BTW, does your com interface really support dispatch (i.e., is it accessible from VB6/VBScript/etc.)? If not, you can't use win32com - you must use comtypes. Or maybe you'd want to use [comtypes](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/) anyway, since its API is bit nicer than win32com.

Comment: I'm not sure.  If IDispatch doesn't show up in the .IDL does that mean it doesn't support IDispatch?  Sorry I don't have access to the code that the type library is generated from.

Comment: @Caleb: Yeah, the interfaces defined in the IDL should inherit from IDispatch. If they don't, you can't use them from win32com.