# Photoshop Manipulation Script Failing

Tags: python, pydev, photoshop, win32com

I'm trying to write a script to apply Photoshop filters. I was looking at [this blog](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html) which seems to have some good advice but when I try the basic example (listed below), I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\EclipseWorkspace\PhotoScript\src\scriptLaunch.py", line 3, in <module>
    psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

I have no idea what's causing this problem. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964805/implement-com-interface-type-library-in-python) has already been implemented so I'm not sure what to do. I'm running python 2.7 on PyDev and Photoshop Elements 10.

My code:

```
import win32com.client

psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application") //the line causing the error

psApp.Open(r"D:\temp\blah.psd")         # Opens a PSD file
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument  # Get active document object
layer = doc.ArtLayers[0]                # Get the bottom-most layer
layer.AdjustBrightnessContrast(20,-15)  # Bright +20, Contrast -15
doc.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the Photoshop API is only available for Photoshop CSx versions and not 'Elements'. I think it's saying the class is unavailable because you don't have the necessary .dll (or whatever the equivalent is if you're using a mac). http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html

Comment: ah that would put a damper on it. Do you happen to know if something like appscript (or some equivalent) would work?

Comment: If your Photoshop software came packaged with the Extendscript Toolkit you should be able to write scripts using javascript, applescript or vbscript. But I think that might be CS only as well. Maybe try the adobe developer forums to see what they say.